# What exactly is meant with PHPs php date.sunrise_zenith and php date.sunset_zenith

Tags: php, date, timezone, find

`date.sunrise_zenith` and `date.sunset_zenith` have been in PHP since Version 5.1, so it's there for more than 10 years.
Unil now, I never had to use these functions, so I never did complain about the very bad manual in this point. No examples , no real explanations.... May be, it isn't used until now by other functions.... 
But what are the meanings?
O.K,`date.default_latitude` and `date.default_longitude`

I find quickly: Search for a place in http://maps.google.de
and the Result will be: If you click on "What's here?" First value is Latitude, second is Longitude. But what exactly is meant by `date.sunrise_zenith` and `date.sunset_zenith`?

First problem I have: **Zenith**, for me, it's when sun is quite above me at midday, so neither at sunset nor at sunrise.

What I found is that most examples  use `90`, so What does `90` mean? `90°` above horizon? This could be, as this would be only possible only when day and night has same length only on *March 21* and *September 21* at equator. But, at every place of the world on *March 21* and *September 21*, day and night have the same length. So this seems to be the reason, why most examples I found say that `date.sunrise_zenith` and `date.sunset_zenith` both are around `90` (°).

So, **my question**: 
How do I determine exactly these two values for a specific place, let's say Munich, Germany?
Aren't there some guys involved in `PHP` who could add this information to php's manual? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It should be 90° but, due to refraction of Earth atmosphere, the sun is visible before its rise and after its set. That means that the center of the sun is 50 arc-minutes below the horizon, so we have to correct the zenith (90°) with this value to obtain the real time of sunrise and sunset.

That's why you have to use `90°50'` as value for `date.sunrise_zenith` and `date.sunset_zenith`.

Some references [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/about-sun-calculator.html)

Answer (score 1):

The PHP functions `date_sunrise()` and `date_sunset()` use `date.sunrise_zenith` and `date.sunset_zenith` to calculate useful sunrise, sunset or twilight times, for example:

- Sunrise: the point where the sun becomes visible.
- Civil twilight: conventionally used to signify the start of dawn.
- Nautical twilight: the point at which the horizon starts being visible at sea.
- Astronomical twilight: the point at which the sun starts being the source of any illumination.

For each of the above there is an astronomical value of `date.sunrise_zenith` and `date.sunset_zenith`.

See examples in [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-sunrise.php)